# Exclude Area from Directional/Ambient Lighting

Tags: three.js

I have a scene that renders several *rooms* on a ground. A room looks like this:

[image]

So you see - it is just an area surrounded by a wall 1 unit in height. I want the user to be able to look inside the room (thats why it has no roof of any kind). But by having no roof the room itself participates in the global lighting I have setup.

Can I somehow add a roof the the room so that it is no longer affected by the global ambient/directional light but, at the same time, have the ability to look inside the room from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you solve this issue by maintaining two scenes. The first scene holds the 3D objects that should be affected by your global lighting. The second scene holds your rooms. By simply adding the ambient and directional light to the first scene, the second one won't be affected.

For clarification, you need two render calls for this setup:

```js
renderer.clear();

renderer.render( scene1, camera );
renderer.render( scene2, camera );
```

Don't forget to set the renderer's `autoClear` property to `false` since you perform the clear operation manually.

Comment: Thanks man. I will try that. I already have several scenes (for the Game UI (menus,  buttons, lists etc) and one for the actual game content (moving entities etc). So that should be a rather easy thing to try... will report back.

Comment: Okay I have tried it out. Thanks again for your response. You suggestion works but I discovered that it is not enough for my needs (that I did not mention in my question). For example I have lights that should affect both scenes (eg. the fire in the room should affect the inside of the room + the outside (if the door of the room is open to the outside). Also I have to give each room a "floor" otherwise your original suggestion also does not seem to work. But I am marking the question as answered and will prob. follow up with a new question.

Comment: here is the follow up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71450056/transparent-light-blocking-objects (With a running example)